# How to manage website development and distribution build path?

Tags: html, requirejs

Several of my recent projects has been using CDN to deliver assets.  I've been having hell of a time changing my asset paths at times of delivery.

My usual routine is: build on localhost with mamp, and use r.js (build tool from require.js) to assemble my final build and deliver that to the client.  But due to the server restrictions, I've been doing mass replace on the build folder to swap out paths before I send my final build.

Is there any way to simplify this process?

Thanks!